# What git functions should i do to accomplish this?

Tags: git

So im having trouble trying to figure this out and maybe im just looking at it wrong but here i go. Say i have a branch A now i create another branch from that branch called branch B. While working on branch B i submit multiple commits afterward to branch A which are C,D,E. Now i should have a branch structure like so

```
A-C-D-E
 \
  B
```

My question lies as how can i input branch B in its correct place so i can make my branch A look lkike A-B-C-D-E i feel like sometimes i will lose code i write if i try and merge branch B with A-C-D-E which would make my branch structure A-C-D-E-B. Since B is created off a branch before i commited changes C-D-E. How can i accomplish this

Comment: That should say  A-C-D-E with A\B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout the branch that has `E`, make a backup branch

```
git branch backup-E
```

and then

```
git rebase branch-that-has-B
```